# Ping timeout in docker container with low ttl values. Expecting Time to live exceeded response

Tags: c#, docker-container, azure-iot-edge, .net-7.0

It seems that pinging inside a docker container for linux with a low TTL results in a TimedOut. I use ping with a low value for ttl, such as 1 or 3 or 4 and so on but the result is a timeout exception.

See this test:

```
# ping 1.1.1.1 -t 3 -w 2
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1075ms
 
# ping 1.1.1.1 -t 15 -w 4
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=37 time=19.7 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=37 time=18.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=37 time=18.5 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=37 time=22.4 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 18.512/19.799/22.407/1.585 ms
```

I created a .Net 7 Console app deployed to a docker linux container to test a Ping request using the IP Address, timeout, buffer, and PingOptions. I increment the TTL in PingOptions from 1 to 30 trying to ping 1.1.1.1 and it does not work with low ttl numbers.

The same code works fine in WSL2 using Ubuntu. It provides the intermediate IP addresses along the way to the final stop of 1.1.1.1 (or any other known IP address).

Why does a ping fail in the docker linux container when the TTL is a low number?

Is there a security setting or other configuration needed to get the ping send to result in a "TtlExpired" instead of "TimedOut"?

Comment: Hi Daniel, have you found any resolution to the issue? If you still face the issue, please try posting this question to [Microsoft Q&A forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/index.html). This might need a deeper investigation to figure out the root cause

Comment: Thanks. After done some more research, I believe it comes down to the way Docker works in containers where elevated permissions are needed to run the container. Secondly, it depends on the ping utility found within the container. In either case, additional documentation is needed in this area as it seems sparce on the internet.  Thanks for your advice and for where to post the question.  I'll give that a try.